# Remove non-HTML special tags from text

Tags: c#, regex

I'm having problem with matching **non-HTML** tags in text mainly, because tags starts with `&lt;` and ends with `&gt;` but not `<` and `>`. So instead `<ref>xx</ref>` i have `&lt;ref&gt;xxx&lt;/ref&gt;`. What I need to do is remove all such tags including their content.

The problem is that some tags may have attributes. I found nice answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200525/regex-for-specifig-tags-and-their-content-groupped-by-the-tag-name/200703#200703) but still there's a problem.

Assuming that I have tag like: `<gallery src=sss>xxx</gallery>` this expression suits perfect:

```
@"<(?<Tag>\w+)[^>)]*>.*?</\k<Tag>>"
```

Reality is quite different and all special characters are escaped, so tag looks like: `&lt;gallery src=sss&gt;xxx&lt;/gallery&gt;`. My problem is to match this king of tags. So far I have this expression:
`@"\&lt\;(?<Tag>\w+)[^\&)]*\&gt\;.*?\&lt\;/\k<Tag>\&gt\;"`. It matches tags with no attributes, but not the one mentioned above. What am I missing?

Second issue is matching `{| |}` tags, because they can be nested. Can you help me with this as well? This expression doesn't do the job: `@"\{\|(?:[^\|\}]|\{\|[^\|\}]*\|\})*\|\}"`

**Edit**: To clarify second issue. I have to match strings that starts with opening tag `{|` then goes some text and ends with `|}` tags. This structure can be nested, so this: `{| xxx {| yyy |} xxx |}` is allowed. I don't know maximum nesting level unfortunately, but lets say that 1 should suit most cases.

---

**Edit 2**: This expressions works for my 1st issue `@"\&lt\;(?<Tag>\w+).*?\&lt\;/\k<Tag>\&gt\;"`. I have noticed that it fails if there's a new line mark between opening and closing tags.

**Edit 3**: This do the job with second issue: `@"\{\|(?>(?!\{\||\|\}).|\{\|(?<N>)|\|\}(?<-N>))*(?(N)(?!))\|\}"`

Comment: Use RegexOption.Singleline for it to work with line breaks. It will be treated as a space character.

Answer (score 1):

so you have HTML-escaped text in which you want to find elements? Why not just unescape it first and then use the code you already have? You can use `HttpServerUtility.HtmlDecode()` for that.

edit:
try this then

```
string text = "PLAIN-TEXT&lt;gallery src=sss&gt;xxx&lt;/gallery&gt;PLAIN-TEXT";
while (text.IndexOf("&lt;") > -1)
    text = Regex.Replace(text, "&lt;\\w+.*?&lt;/\\w+&gt;", "");
Console.WriteLine(text);
```

in case it is confusing: the loop is for the nested tags. You could handle them with Regex to but that get complicated.

Comment: Because then these tags would be indistinguishable from real tags.

Answer (score 0):

This regex should (partially) work:

```
@"&lt;.+?&gt;(.*?)&lt;/.+?&gt;"
```

That being said, regex is not an appropriate tool for parsing (X)HTML. Here's a better solution:

1. Add an identifier after the `&lt;`, ie: BOGUS000 : `YourStr.Replace("&lt;", "&lt;BOGUS000")`
2. Now convert the `&lt;` and `%gt;` to `<` and `>` using `HttpServerUtility.HtmlDecode()`
3. Parse the file using an XML parser
4. Now you know all elements which have a name starting with your identifier (here `BOGUS000`) are, well, bogus. They can be removed.
5. Profit ! :)

I am not sure I understand your second issue.

Comment: This expression will fail when tags will be nested.

Comment: no, it just won't remove all of them, but since ".*?" will ensure that only inner-most tag is matched, you can just execute it multiple times  until not tags left.

Comment: @Ventus Regex is not an appropriate tool to parse (X)HTML, this happens to be the same thing, but with different opening and closing tags. You do what you can.

Comment: @Aillyn I'm not sure that this the same as (X)HTML, because document is not a structure. It's just a text containing some tags, not tags containing text...

Comment: @Ventus it does appear to be an XML fragment though, which is beyond the scope of a regular expression to fully describe.

Comment: @irkz: `.*?` will NOT ensure that the innermost tag is matched.  Apply the regex `<(\w+)>.*?</\1>` to `<A><A></A></A>` and you'll see it matches from the first opening tag to the first closing tag, leaving the second `</A>` hanging.

Answer (score 0):

add RegexOptions.Singleline to the Regex.Replace() call (yes I know, it feels backward) to address the issue with tag spanning multiple lines not matching.

second issue: How is it not exactly the same problem? The regex is given to you - just substitute the bounding strings and done.

Comment: second one is not the same as first one. First was: `<tagName>content</tagName>`, but second is `{| content |}`. The problem is that second one can also looks like this: `{| content {| nested content |} {| another nested content |} content |}`. For me it is totally different than first one.

Comment: No, it is the same. You have a blob of text which may contain things like `text[opening sequence]other text[opening sequence]more text[closing sequence]and even more text[closing sequence]text yet again`
The `[opening sequence]` and `[closing sequence]` vary, but algorithm for resolving them is exactly the same.